# I can't do res.redirect('/dashbord')

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I have a problem with redirecting to another header in Node.js. I trigger this /login header

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res) = {
const data = req.body
const user:IUser = {
name: data.name,
password: data.password
}

        const loginAuth = new Auth()
        const {foundUser, token, refreshToken} = await loginAuth.Login(user.name, user.password)
    
        if(foundUser) {
            res.cookie("JwtToken", token, { httpOnly: true })
            res.redirect(200, '/dashboard');
            // return res.status(200).json({token}).end();
        } else {
            res.redirect(307, '/');
        }
    })
```

FoundUser is either true or false. It's true if it find a user with the name and password. If it does i want to redirect to /dashboard. But when i trigger that header nothing happens. I use express. Here is /dashboard

```
app.get('/dashboard', Authorization, (req, res) => {         
const user:IUser = req.payload         
res.render('dashboard', {user})     
})
```

I have tried to google but can't seem to find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first try returning the response. Also, I would return the correct response code and not override with 200:

```
return res.redirect('/dashboard');
```

Comment: Hello, still the same. Nothing happens

Comment: Edited my answer. I think overriding the response code with 200 is also a potential problem